# Python write b'xxxx' to config and read it

Tags: python, encryption, passwords, configparser

i have encrypted a password and the result is like this: b'&Ti\xcfK\x15\xe2\x19\x0c'
i want to save it to an config file and reload it
so i can decrypt it and i can use it again as password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# To save it:
with open('file-to-save-password', 'bw') as f:
    f.write( b'&Ti\xcfK\x15\xe2\x19\x0c')

# To read it:
with open('file-to-save-password', 'br') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Python's [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) builtin function.

```
with open('foo.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(b'&Ti\xcfK\x15\xe2\x19\x0c')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
# to write the file

cryptpw = "your encrypted password"

config = open("/path/to/config/file/pw.config","w")
config.write(cryptpw)
config.close()

# to reopen it

config = open("/path/to/config/file/pw.config","r")
print(config.read())
config.close()
```

It's up to you what you do with the contents of that file, i just chose to print it.

Answer (score 0):

[python persistence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/persistence.html) is useful here. e.g:

```
import shelve

with shelve.open('secrets') as db:
    db['password'] = b'&Ti\xcfK\x15\xe2\x19\x0c'
```